# change javascript property giving a rule of modification

Tags: javascript, algorithm, class

I have the following class structured as follows:

```
class Player {
    constructor(id) { 
       this.limits.playaces = 1;
       this.actions.playaces = 0;
    }
}
```

I would like to apply a modification function so that it looks like this

```
var player = new Player();
player.modifyAction("playaces","++"); //increments playaces from actions
player.modifyAction("playaces","--"); //decrements playaces from actions
player.modifyAction("playaces","+4"); //adds 4 to playaces from actions
player.modifyAction("playaces","-1"); //subtract 1 from playaces from actions
```

I would like to avoid making a map, so I thought eval() was the best course of action but I was wondering if I could use a lexer/parser instead of using eval and shifting to a new object paradigm, keeping the class definition as short as possible.

Can it be done?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) This is trivial to parse, you're right there's no need for `eval`. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Why not just `player.actions.playaces += 1;` ?

Comment: I could do that. But I would like to not type that long line, especially since I will need more properties inside 'actions' along with other properties that will require manipulation. Having one flexible setter/getter like this would offer me more speed for coding/debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
class Player {
    constructor(id) { 
        this.id = id 
        this.playaces = 1;
    }
    incrementPlayaces() {
        this.playaces++
        console.log(this.playaces)
    }
    decrementPlayaces() {
        this.playaces--
        console.log(this.playaces)
    }
    addPlayaces(val) {
        this.playaces += val
        console.log(this.playaces)
    }
}

let player = new Player('id');

player.incrementPlayaces()
player.decrementPlayaces()
player.addPlayaces(-4)
player.addPlayaces(+5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. I would like to have something of a lexer/parser ( just like eval does ) but without eval:

```
function modifyAction(property,expression) {
    eval("this."+property+expression+";");
}
```

Then I would call it in the following fashion:

```
player.modifyAction("playaces","++") //evaluating to this.playaces++;
player.modifyAction("playaces","+=1") //evaluating to this.playaces += 1;
player.modifyAction("playaces","=1") //evaluating to this.playaces = 1;
player.modifyAction("cardsToPlay","> this.cardsInHand") //evaluating to this.cardsToPlay > this.cardsInHand, if the function were to return an comparison result.
```

I would like to avoid eval, due to the obvious issues of security and performance it brings. I have researched about Function but I have yet to come across an answer for this. I was thinking of adding a lexer like [this](https://github.com/aaditmshah/lexer) to the object but i'm not sure if this is the correct path to follow.